# how to limit or block broadcast traffic on ASR920 service instance EVC

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, switching, cisco-asr, evc

I don't want to turn off all port,
I want to block completly broadcast traffic,
or the best to limit rate to 500 pps broadcast, all more to drop.
Is there any way to do it on Cisco ASR920?

I have service instances on the port.
On Cisco asr1000 series I found commands as below, but don't find it on ASR920,
but something like it or similar probably will do the work:

```
Router(config-if)# service instance 1 ethernet Router(config-if-srv)# encapsulation dot1q 1-4094
Router(config-if-srv)# storm-control unicast cir 8000
Router(config-if-srv)# storm-control broadcast cir 1500000
Router(config-if-srv)# storm-control multicast cir 980000000
Router(config-if-srv)# bridge-domain 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Storm Control is done on the interface on the 920, not the service instance. Take the following command for example:

storm-control broadcast level 5 5

storm-control action trap

This would filter broadcast traffic at 5 percent of the interface speed (and send a trap alert), and stop filtering once it drops back below 5 percent.